# How to host dotnet core on Ubuntu and make it accessible from LAN?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, proxy, .net-core, lan

I have a basic dotnet core (2.2 version) application hosted on Ubuntu pc using Nginx server. It works perfectly when I try to access it from localhost, but when I try to access it from mac (Ubuntu has IP address of 192.168.1.7) which is on the same LAN network there is a message that this site can't be loaded. I configured a reverse proxy server using this manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2.

I believe that nginx is configured properly but there is something wrong with kestrel which runs dotnet core app. Firewall on nginx is disabled. Does anybody have idea why kestrel doesn't load the site?

Any advice would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.